# Getting an error in my test enviorment in Ubercart website while checkout in cart/checkout

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

I am getting an error for authencated customer while checkout from cart in this path cart/checkout. Here is the error message "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

I am unable to find any solution.